# Error : 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)'?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

Error : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I Am Making a Search Button that will send the search Query to fragment And From there it loads the URL with a search query

for eg if I search pen in the search bar. the query will send using bundle and will load in webview in another fragment.

```
Activity code
    firstFragmentBtn = findViewById(R.id.fragment1btn);
    secondFragmentBtn = findViewById(R.id.fragment2btn);

     searchView = findViewById(R.id.edit_query);
  

  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          bundle.putString("sendData", searchView.getQuery().toString());

          fragment1 fragobj = new fragment1();
          fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
          replaceFragment(new fragment1());
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
          return false;
      }
  });

    firstFragmentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            replaceFragment(new fragment1());

        }
    });

    secondFragmentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            replaceFragment(new fragment2());

        }
    });
```

fragment code

```
  WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
  // error in this line
   String  message = bundle.getString("SendData"); ????

    webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/search?q=" + message);




    return view;
```

Answer (score 1):

in `putString("sendData")` whereas in `getString` it is "SendData" put same in both either sendData or SendData.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment inside `onCreateView()`

```
if(getArguments().getString("sendData") != null)
{
    String message = getArguments().getString("sendData");

.
.
.
```